# How to retrieve data in database with UTC datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, datetime, timezone

I need to fetch a data in our database as a report using Ruby on Rails but I have a problem with the date-time ex:

This order was made on:

[image]

but on our database it's dated plus 8hours because we saved it as UTC:

[image]

Then I have a query:

```
Spree::Order
            .joins(user:[:corporate_account])
            .includes(line_items:[:variant])
            .where('spree_orders.completed_at IS NOT NULL')
            .ransack(@params[:q])
```

start_date and end_date are converted into:

```
@params[:q][start_date] = params[:q][start_date].to_datetime.beginning_of_day
@params[:q][end_date]   = params[:q][end_date].to_datetime.end_of_day
```

to get the orders starting at 12:00 am til 11:59:59 pm end of day.

I am not allowed to change how we saved the date-time in our database and we can't make a cut-off.

I can't also add 1 day at end of the day because the orders will have a discrepancy.

I also tried converting PST to UTC doesn't work because let's say I want to generate a report at 5 pm right now with a date of `2021/12/01`, I have to convert it to end of the day so that's `2021/12/01 11:59:59` it won't include the orders made at 5 pm `2021/12/01` since it'll be offset on the database with 8hrs, it'll be saved as `2021/12/02 1am`

So my question is how would you query a data with such date-time offset?

Comment: Did you configure a timezone in `config/application.rb`, like `config.time_zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"` ?

Comment: depending on the database you can write a query to convert the date time to required timezone. E.g in mysql you can use `convert_tz(date_value, original_timezone, new_timezone)` to convert between timezones.

Comment: @littleforest hello, thank you for the response. yes sir Ive configure it and I think it how I configure the dates.

Comment: @AbdulRehman hello. We cant do that. we cant change directly on the database because some formatting are expected to be in UTC format for the view to show it as a PST.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
timezone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
start_date = Date.parse(@params[:q][:start_date])
end_date = Date.parse(@params[:q][:end_date])
@params[:q][:start_date] = Time.find_zone(timezone).local(start_date.year, start_date.month, start_date.day, 0, 0, 0)
@params[:q][:end_date] = Time.find_zone(timezone).local(end_date.year, end_date.month, end_date.day, 23, 59, 59)
```

For example:

```
timezone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
start_date = Date.parse("2021-11-30")
end_date = Date.parse("2021-11-30")
@params[:q][:start_date] = Time.find_zone(timezone).local(2021, 11, 30, 0, 0, 0) # => Tue, 30 Nov 2021 00:00:00.000000000 PST -08:00
@params[:q][:start_date].utc # 2021-11-30 08:00:00 UTC
@params[:q][:end_date] = Time.find_zone(timezone).local(2021, 11, 30, 23, 59, 59) # Tue, 30 Nov 2021 23:59:59.000000000 PST -08:00
@params[:q][:end_date].utc # 2021-12-01 07:59:59 UTC
```